# adding text from html input as value into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, records

I wonder if anyone could help me with my problem? I want to send value (input text) to mysql database but it is always blank text. I am the beginner and I think I've made stupid mistake... Code:

```
<form name="form" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="nick">
    <input type="text" name="message" height="300px">
</form>
        <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
{ 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$nickval = $_POST['nick'];
$messageval = $_REQUEST['message'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO Messages (nick, message)
VALUES ('$_GET[nick]', '$_GET[message]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Messages");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Nick</th>
<th>Message</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nick'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
}
?>
<form method="POST" action=''>
<input type="submit" name="button1"  value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using $_POST, $_REQUEST, and also $_GET? Your form method is `POST` so you should only be using `$_POST` to retrieve your inputs from the the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<input type="submit" name="button1"  value="Send">
```

needs to go inside your first form, where your other inputs are.

```
<form name="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nick">
    <input type="text" name="message" height="300px">
    <input type="submit" name="button1"  value="Send">
</form>
```

And also @Joe T's answer. Many problems wrong with this question it seems

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should look more like this, the other answer is also right (about moving your submit button inside the same form with your inputs)

```
$nickval =  mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn , $_POST['nick']);
$messageval = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn , $_POST['message']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Messages (nick, message)
VALUES ( '$nickval', '$messageval')";
```

As the commenter wrote, don't use $_REQUEST and $_GET, only $_POST is used here.
And if you don't escape your inputs, (as i've done here with mysqli_real_escape_string) you are asking for a world of hurt.